# Translating Alpine.js x-transitions to Vue.js transition classes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, alpine.js

So, I have a slight conceptual problem. I'll also admit I am primarily a back end developer and loose front end developer looking to learn better UI/UX principles/frameworks etc so apologies in advanced if this is a relatively straightforward question.

I have the the following `x-transition` example that was built in Alpine.js:

```
<div
    x-show="open"
    x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
    x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
    x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
>...</div>
```

I have attempted to translate this to the transition animation in Vue.js

```
<transition
    name="custom-classes-transition"
    enter-class="transition ease-out duration-100"
    enter-active-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leave-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
    leave-active-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
>
    <div v-if="open>

    </div>
</transition>
```

But, alas, nothing. What to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for

```
<transition
    enter-active-class="transition duration-100 ease-out"
    leave-active-class="transition duration-75 ease-in"
    enter-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leave-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
>
```

Comment: Same for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this particular question comes from trying to use one of [Tailwind's UI Hero Section components](https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes) but using VueJS instead of Alpine (which is what Tailwind UI uses).

in this particular example you will also have to change Alpine's **x-show** and **x-data** for VueJs **v-if** directive. (at least that's how i got it to work).

Also you will have to declare the open property within the vue data like so: (My component's name was Cover instead of HeroSection)

```
export default {
  name: 'Cover',
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  }
}
```